# Using custom where clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

My active record is

```
$ql = $this->db->select('course_id')->from('tbl_course_choice')->where('course_id',$course_id)->get();

    if( $ql->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        $data = array(
        'teacher_name_1' => 'mehdi'
        );
        $this->db->where('teacher_name_1', NULL);
        $this->db->where('course_id', $course_id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_course_choice', $data);
    } else {
        $a = array(
            'course_id' => $course_id,
            'course_code' => $course_code,
            'course_title' => $course_title,
            'course_type' => $course_type,
            'credit_hours' => $credit_hours,
            'contact_hours' => $contact_hours,
            'section' => $section,
            'teacher' => $teacher, 
            'pre_requisite' => $pre_requisite,
            'year' => $year,
            'semester' => $semester,
            'offering_year' => $offering_year,
            'offering_session' => $offering_session,
            'teacher_name_1' => $teacher_name_1


            );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_course_choice', $a);
    }
```

i need to check if filed is null then insert or update  else insert in other filed

```
    if {
    $this->db->where('teacher_name_1', NULL);
    $this->db->where('course_id', $course_id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_course_choice', $data);
} 
elseif {
    $this->db->where('teacher_name_1', IS NOT NULL);
    $this->db->where('teacher_name_2', NULL);
    $this->db->where('course_id', $course_id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_course_choice', $data);
}
```

How can i do this to check if is null then inset or update. anyone can help me??

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom string

```
$this->db->where('teacher_name_1 IS NULL', NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: i tried but not working, seems is unable to check if field is null or not , any other way to check if is null or not

Comment: In my case its work as like $this->db->where('teacher_name_1 != ', '');